# Android Studio 2.2.2: All packages are not available for download

Tags: android, android-studio, sdk

I installed Android Studio 2.2.2 on my system. After when I openend one of the projects which have `compileSdkVersion 23`, got following error,

> ```
> >  Error:Failed to find target with hash string 'android-22' in:
> > href="install.android.platform">Install missing platform(s) and sync
> > project</a>
> ```

I know this error means I need to download sdk packages but I'm not able to do so. Also in my SDK Manager I don't see all APIs to install

[image]

Comment: Try to rebuild project or clean project, and update your SDK

Comment: Possible duplicate of [All packages are not available for download error in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38714165/all-packages-are-not-available-for-download-error-in-android)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I was facing the same issue. For me, it got resolved by setting proxy settings.

**Android Studio > File  > Settings >appearance and behavior> System Settings > HTTP Proxy**

I would suggest checking any proxy is required to enable internet for your android studio. Hope this will help somebody.

Comment: Brilliant suggestion!

Comment: I suggest to use tor for windows as proxy, [get tor](https://thetorproject.github.io/gettor/)

Comment: it seems to be a bug in android studio

Answer (score 4):

> Open Android SDK Manager

1. Click on Tools.
2. Click on Android.
3. Click on SDK Manager.

Update your SDK's

Then Sync ,Re-Build and Restart Your Project

Answer (score 2):

"Launch Standalone SDK Manager" is not available in newer versions.

Just select "SDK Tools" tab, then "Android SDK Build-Tools and place a check next to 23.0.1, 23.0.2, 23.0.3, etc. and any others you may want to install.

Select Apply and when complete, press Finish.

Rebuild and see if that helps.

Answer (score 2):

***If you were in China***, maybe because of the host problem.

I had resolved this problem with 3 steps

the android sdk platform resources are download from host `dl.google.com`

so first step, get the available ip address for `dl.google.com`

(1) visit the [ping tools](http://ping.chinaz.com/)

[image]

[image]

(2) get the 'best' ip address for `dl.google.com`

according to the pic best one is `203.208.41.73`

(3) set the local host for your computer

[image]

(4) install sdk platform again

[image]

***If you were in China*** hope this trick could help you

Answer (score 1):

You need add check in, open Settings -> Appearance & Behavior -> System Settings -> Android SDK -> SDK Tools -> Launch Standalone SDK Manager

FIRST SDKPlatform to 23
[image]

SECOND Tools to 23
[image]

and ever end sync up..

Comment: I don't see any components to install, only API 24 is visible which I have installed

Comment: really don't see your SDK Manager ?

Comment: there is no such "Launch Standalone SDK Manager" link or button in Android studio.. at least on windoows