# Android Studio - No Resource found that matches the name

Tags: android, android-studio

I am facing an issue in Android studio

[image]

I have tried to update the recent build-tools version to `27.0.1` and SDK version to `28` but it throws the exception

[image]

**Update:**

I have mentioned the app level `build.gradle` file content below,

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    buildToolsVersion '27.0.1'

    dexOptions {
        jumboMode true
        javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
    }

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "XXXX.XXXX.XXXX"
        minSdkVersion 17
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 27
        versionName "1.0.19"
        multiDexEnabled true
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            shrinkResources true
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
    }

    aaptOptions.cruncherEnabled = false
    aaptOptions.useNewCruncher = false
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:11.8.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crash:11.8.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:11.8.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.0.2'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:+'
    compile 'com.liferay.mobile:liferay-screens:2.1.1'
    compile 'com.liferay.mobile:liferay-material-viewset:2.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:+'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:+'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:+'
    compile 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:1.2.1'
    compile 'com.android.volley:volley:1.0.0'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:exifinterface:+'
    compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
    compile 'com.github.woxthebox:draglistview:1.5.1'
    compile 'com.github.lzyzsd:circleprogress:+'
    compile 'com.github.PhilJay:MPAndroidChart:v3.0.1'
    compile 'me.gujun.android.taggroup:library:1.4@aar'
    compile 'com.akexorcist:RoundCornerProgressBar:2.0.3'
    compile 'com.prolificinteractive:material-calendarview:1.4.3'
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
        maven { url "http://dl.bintray.com/nhpatt/liferay-mobile" }
        google()
    }
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Please anyone help to find out the solution.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40416500/android-studio-2-2-2-all-packages-are-not-available-for-download

Comment: I have tried using auto detect proxy option but not working

Comment: post your dependency

Comment: @John Joe I have updated my question . Please check it

Comment: Use the SDK manager to download them

Comment: https://android.stackexchange.com/a/170964

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like a strange issue in Android Studio. Found a Workaround from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41505617/strange-error-after-updatng-android-studio) post.

Thanks to [Veener](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2867656/veener) who has posted the answer that actually solved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Just check whether the auto import libraries is working. Whether the studio is importing te required libraries in your maiñ activity