# All Packages are not available for download Android studio 3.1.2

Tags: android

Install all packages for Android P, after that create new project with Kotlin support and facing the error **Failed to find target with hash string 'android-28'**

[image]

[image]

[image]

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rWOfK.png)
Action Performed:

1- Clean/Rebuild Project

2- Proxy is working fine in setting and gradle.properties file

3- Invalidate Caches/Restart

Comment: https://developer.android.com/preview/setup-sdk

Answer (score 0):

maybe you can try to set the local host for `dl.google.com`

https://stackoverflow.com/a/52981324/4593755

find out the proper ip address for `dl.google.com` in your country, then set the local host.